# How is $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ a subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_p)^{ab}$

Tags: galois-theory, local-field

Let $p$ be a prime. How is $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ a subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_p)^{ab}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}\def\FF{\mathbb{F}}\def\Gal{\mathrm{Gal}}$ There are some shorter things to say here, which do not fully answer the question, and then some deep things to say which do. I don't think there is an easy way to fully answer the question. To be clear, there is more than one way to embed $\FF_p^{\times}$ into $\Gal(\QQ_p)^{ab}$; I am trying to give what I think most people would consider the "natural" embedding.

Throughout, let $\zeta_m$ denote a primitive $m$-th root of unity.

**Shorter things:** The extension $\QQ_p(\zeta_p)$ has Galois group naturally isomorphic to $\FF_p^{\times}$: The element $a \in \FF_p^{\times}$ corresponds to $\zeta_p \mapsto \zeta_p^a$. The proof that this is the Galois group is exactly the same as over $\QQ$. (Sketch: Every Galois symmetry must be of the form $\zeta_p \mapsto \zeta_p^a$, so this gives an embedding of the Galois group into $ \FF_p^{\times}$. To prove equality, we must show that the $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial, $x^{p-1} + \cdots + x + 1$, is irreducible in $\QQ_p$. Substitute $x = y+1$ and use Eisenstein's criterion.)

Thus, we have a surjection $\Gal(\QQ_p)^{ab} \to \Gal(\QQ_p(\zeta_p)/\QQ_p) \cong \FF_p^{\times}$. You are asking me to split this surjection.

By a similar argument we have $\Gal(\QQ_p(\zeta_{p^k})/\QQ_p) \cong (\ZZ/p^k \ZZ)^{\times}$. There is an obvious short exact sequence 
$$1 \to (1+p \ZZ/p^k \ZZ)/p^k \ZZ \to  (\ZZ/p^k \ZZ)^{\times} \to \FF_p^{\times} \to 0. \quad (\ast)$$
The sequence $(\ast)$ has a unique splitting! Lift $a \in \FF_p^{\times}$ to the unique element $\tau(a) \in (\ZZ/p^k \ZZ)^{\times}$ which is $a \bmod p$ and obeys $a^p=a$. Taking the inverse limit on $k$, we obtain what is called the Teichmuller lift $\tau : \FF_p^{\times} \to \ZZ_p^{\times}$. Thus, $\FF_p^{\times}$ acts on $\bigcup_k \QQ_p(\zeta_{p^k})$ by $\zeta_{p^k} \mapsto \zeta_{p^k}^{\tau(a)}$ where $\tau(a)$ is the Tiechmuller lift of $a$.

Let $m$ be any positive integer and write $m = p^k n$ where $p$ does not divide $n$. Then $\QQ_p(\zeta_m) = \QQ_p(\zeta_n, \zeta_{p^k})$. The extension $\QQ_p(\zeta_{p^k})/\QQ_p$ is totally ramified and $\QQ_p(\zeta_n)/\QQ_p$ is unramified, so these extensions are disjoint and $\Gal(\QQ_p(\zeta_m)/\QQ_p) \cong \Gal(\QQ_p(\zeta_{p^k})/\QQ_p) \times \Gal(\QQ_p(\zeta_n)/\QQ_p)$. We can define an action of $\FF_p^{\times}$ on $\QQ_p(\zeta_m)$ by acting on $\QQ_p(\zeta_p)$ as described above and acting trivially on $\QQ_p(\zeta_n)$.

That is as far as I can get before I use deep tools.

**Deeper things** In fact, the local Kronecker-Weber theorem tells us that every abelian extension of $\QQ_p$ is contained in some $\QQ_p(\zeta_m)$. So I have described an action of $\FF_p^{\times}$ on the full $\QQ_p^{ab}$.

If you don't want to invoke local Kronecker-Weber, you can invoke local class field theory instead. Local class field theory tells us that $\Gal(\QQ_p)^{ab}$
is isomorphic to the profinite completion of $\QQ_p^{\times}$. Inside $\QQ_p^{\times}$, let $\ZZ_p^{\times}$ be $p$-adic integers which are nonzero $\bmod p$ and let $U_p$ be $p$-adic integers which are $1 \bmod p$. We have a short exact sequence $1 \to U_p \to \ZZ_p^{\times} \to \FF_p^{\times} \to 1$ which is split by the Teichmuller lift, so $\ZZ_p^{\times} \cong U_p \times \FF_p^{\times}$ and we get $\FF_p^{\times} \subset U_p \subset \QQ_p^{\times} \subset \Gal(\QQ_p)^{ab}$.

Presumably, if I understood local class field theory well enough, I could describe the explicit map $\QQ_p^{\times} \to \Gal(\QQ_p)^{ab}$ and restrict it to the Teichmuller representatives $\FF_p^{\times}$ sitting inside $\QQ_p^{\times}$. However, I do not.

Comment: It’s not all that difficult. It’s enough to say how any element of $z\in\Bbb Z_p$ acts on the $p$-power roots of unity — the action is trivial on a root of period prime to $p$ — “$z$” sends $\zeta$ to $\zeta^z$ (but if you need it to accord with the reciprocity law you want to send $\zeta$ to $\zeta^{z^{-1}}$). Notice that any $z\in1+p^r\Bbb Z_p$ acts trivially this way on $p^r$-th roots of unity.

Comment: @Lubin Right, but this is using Kronecker-Weber, as I say earlier in the answer. I am in the usual situation of not knowing what level I am supposed to answer the OP on, but it seems reasonable that this question might be asked by someone who doesn't know KW or, even if they do, they want to be allowed to compute the Artin map without figuring out how to embed their abelian extension into a cyclotomic one.

Comment: For example, their abelian extension might be $\mathbb{Q}_p(a^{1/m})$ where $m$ divides $p-1$. As I recall, it is a pain to give an explicit formula for the embedding of $a^{1/m}$ into the cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer thank you so much for such a detailed concrete answer!